# Deep Learning to estimate what is beyond the edge

Tags: deep-learning, reference-request

I have an image of some data which is approximately 4,000 x 8,000 pixels.  I am interested in finding out if anyone has used a deep learning algorithm to predict what would be on the image if it extended 100 more pixels in each direction.  I would imagine that the data could be trained on smaller rectangles, and then the rules developed would be used to extend beyond the image given.  Has anyone seen a problem like this (and is there a reference)?   Even if not, what deep learning scheme would be best for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the closest problem that has been addressed with deep learning is image inpainting, that is, filling a blacked out region in the image:

[image]

For instance, this paper: [Semantic Image Inpainting with Perceptual and Contextual Losses](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.07539).

So it is certainly possible to fill missing information from an image with deep learning.

Comment: Ah, good catch.  This looks close enough to what I was looking for.  Thanks!.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few [papers](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.07157.pdf) on predicting the next image in a set of video sequences. So I would familiarize yourself with those first.

With that being said it is definitely possible to do this sort of things using ML. There has been a lot of work on recurrent layers for Convolutional Neural Nets. These at a high level seems like it would be a good candidate to investigate for your initial architectures.

Here is some info on RCNNs:

Example RCNN in keras: [link](https://github.com/jacobzweig/Keras-RCNN/blob/master/Keras_RCNN.py)

Papers on RCNNs: [link](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2015/papers/Liang_Recurrent_Convolutional_Neural_2015_CVPR_paper.pdf)   [link](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5634-convolutional-neural-networks-with-intra-layer-recurrent-connections-for-scene-labeling.pdf)

Comment: I've looked at algorithms for next image, and I don't think the continuity assumptions are quite the same.  The inpainting in the other answer is much closer.  The other references are definitely interesting though.  Thanks!.